# How to use underscore lib from DefinitelyTyped with typescript?

Tags: typescript, underscore.js, definitelytyped

[DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped) has provided a underscore declaration file, which defines a `List` interface, and used it heavily in the code.

```
// Common interface between Arrays and jQuery objects
interface List {
    [index: number]: any;
    length: number;
}

interface UnderscoreStatic {
    sortBy(list: List, iterator?: any, context?: any): any;
    groupBy(list: List, iterator: any): any;
    countBy(list: List, iterator: any): any;
}
```

I'm trying to use the `countBy` function:

```
// <reference path="../DefinitelyTyped/underscore/underscore.d.ts" />

declare var _: UnderscoreStatic;

_.countBy([1,2,3], function(item) {
    return item%2;
});
```

When I compile the file, it throws error:

```
> tsc commons.ts

> E:/commons.ts(5,0): Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target:
    Could not apply type 'List' to argument 1, which is of type 'number[]'
```

I don't know why this error happened, since `number[]` fit the interface `List`.

Where is wrong, and how to fix it?

Comment: 2016 update: `import * as _ from "underscore";`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to pass an object compatible with the `List` interface, which is an array with a length:

```
/// <reference path="underscore.d.ts" />

var list: List;
list[0] = 1;
list[1] = 2;
list[2] = 3;
list.length = 3;

_.countBy(list, function (item) {
    return item % 2;
});
```

In all honesty, an array technically fulfils this as it has a length property - but the above code compiles.

The shorthand version of this is a bit nasty:

```
/// <reference path="underscore.d.ts" />

var list = <List><any> [1, 2, 3];

_.countBy(list, function (item) {
    return item % 2;
});
```

Comment: I can't image I have to add a `length` to an array each time I use it, just in order to make it compile.

Comment: Couldn't you also just cast the array: `_.countBy((<List>[1,2,3]) ...` etc. ?  (Don't have the underscore lib to hand so can't test this).

Comment: You get "Cannot convert number[] to List". One alternative would be to accept that `number[]` would be a better typing in `underscore.d.ts` as we know it will have an indexer and a length. You could get away with the really hideous: `var list: List = <List><any> [1, 2, 3];`

Comment: @Freewind I have added a short-hand version that is a bit nasty, but means you don't have to use the expanded version. Bear in mind this could well be a mistake in the `.d.ts` definition - a regular underscore user might be able to confirm, in which case I'm happy to submit an update.

Comment: Update - I have submitted a pull request on Definitely Typed to remove the List interface in favour of using the `any[]` type, which will allow normal use of underscore.

Answer (score 2):

## Update 2021

Add the following dependencies to `package.json`:

```js
  "dependencies": {
    "underscore": "^1.13.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/underscore": "^1.11.4"
  }
```

Then run:

```bash
$ npm install
```

In your TypeScript files, import `underscore` using:

```js
import * as _ from 'underscore';
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Typescript 2.0, you can import underscore with the `import` statement like below:

```
import * as _ from "underscore";
```

Then, call any underscore function using `_.<function_name>`.

PS: don't forget to install underscore library with npm for example.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the underscore TypeScript definition file matches the version of underscore you're using. The signature of countBy has changed and if the TS definition didn't match the underlying JS you'd get some unexpected behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

First add underscore typing:

```
npm install typings --global
typings install dt~jasmine --save --global
```

Then reference this file in your .ts source

```
/// <reference path="../../../typings/underscore.d.ts" />
```

Then import underscore to avoid compilation errors (be careful - underscore lib in this case should be installed as npm reference, not bower: **npm install underscore --save**)

```
import _ = require('underscore');
```

Then use underscore as usual using **"_"** global variable

```
_.isNumber(123);
```